# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" in Laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.7 version. I got the below error for `users_activations` table while run the command `php artisan migrate`

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `auf`.`#sql-1ecc_fa` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `users_activations` add constraint `users_activations_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

**`users_activations` table**

```
Schema::create('users_activations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade'); // got error for this line
        $table->string('token');
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });
```

**`user` table**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('role_id')->default('1');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have already googling for the error.

I have changed

`$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();`

of `users_activations` table with

`$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');`. But not worked.

Somebody help me please ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign key should be the same type as the id, change your foreign key to bigInteger:

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
```